# Android gradle - how to search multiple respositories for gradle dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, repository, android-gradle-plugin

So our group has a private maven repository with a large number of libraries 'in-house'. So there only available on a vpn.  bintray and jcenter is available on my vpn.  What i want to do is have gradle check for a dependency first on the private maven repo, if not found then search bintray/jcenter for the library.  How can i do this ? this is what i have tried:

In the top level build.gradle file i have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://myprivateRepo.com/libraries"
    }
        jcenter()
    }
```

my assumption was that it would first check maven private repo and then check with jcenter afterwards but it seems to not be working, can anyone verify the set up ?

Comment: Check your project-level `build.gradle`. In a typical Android Studio project, that sets up `jcenter()` as an available artifact repository for projects (which is why we usually don't have to specify `jcenter()` in our modules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the repositories for your buildscripts (or plugins). You need to add it to your project / dependencies level.

Using it with `buildscript` will resolve plugins. You need that e.g. if you are using apt: `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

Remove the wrapping `buildscript` block:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://myprivateRepo.com/libraries" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile "my:library:1.0.0"
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively just set it on the project root `build.gradle` and apply to all projects like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://myprivateRepo.com/libraries" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```